# Hide "index.php" from "www.blahblah.com/index.php"

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to hide "index.php" from "www.blahblah.com/index.php"? How to do that?

Please help, I've tons of codes now i'm planning to hide `index.php` from URL. I googled and found that you first need to create `.htaccess` file. But i don't know where to start it? and Should i need to create that file along with my projects? And what to type inside that file?

Comment: `index.php` you don't have to hide in the url bar! You can just direct to the `directory name` and it automatic choose the `index.php` file! and it's not shown in the url bar! Like: `localhost/Sandbox` (If you have a file in there called index.php this get's called)

Comment: Okay, so how to do that?

Comment: If you make links do it like this: `<a href="/Sandbox">home</a>` instead of `<a href="/Sandbox/index.php">home</a>`

Comment: @Rizier123 I don't get you still :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create .htaccess file then copy the code below
change 'project_folder_name' of the folder of your project
if your project is in the root folder just put '/'

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /project_folder_name

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sorrry but don't understand ..waht do you mean by `root folder`?